# Python on Mac OSX 10.7.5 Reportlab, import error for submodule

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, importerror, reportlab

Mac OS X 10.7.5
Python 2.7
Reportlab 2.6

I'm getting good ol' import error when trying to call on a submodule in reportlab:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "reportlab.py", line 1, in
> <module>
>     import reportlab   File "/Users/maggielee/Documents/pythons/reportlab.py", line 2, in <module>
>     from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing, String ImportError: No module named graphics.shapes
```

:(   I'm pretty sure reportlab.graphics is in there.
As a noob I cant embed an image, but here it is, in ... site-packages, same as beautifulsoup et al:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-ZMst96R_MYUENKR0FjcFJjaG8

here are the steps I tried: 
     python setup.py install

```
> ...
> ########## SUMMARY INFO #########
> ################################################
> #Attempting install of _rl_accel, sgmlop & pyHnj
> #extensions from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/reportlab-2.6/src/rl_addons/rl_accel'
> ################################################
> ################################################
> #Attempting install of _renderPM
> #extensions from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/reportlab-2.6/src/rl_addons/renderPM'
> # installing without freetype no ttf, sorry!
> # You need to install a static library version of the freetype2 software
> # If you need truetype support in renderPM
> # You may need to edit setup.cfg (win32)
> # or edit this file to access the library if it is installed
> ################################################ Standard T1 font curves already downloaded
```

yea, ok, I dont know what that means, so let's try: 
    python setup.py tests

then it churns thru some tests, details some errors and tells me (failures=1 errors=6)

So, let us try
     easy_install reportlab

result:

```
> Searching for reportlab Best match: reportlab 2.6 Adding reportlab 2.6
> to easy-install.pth file
> 
> Using
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
> Processing dependencies for reportlab Finished processing dependencies
> for reportlab
```

so sad, been fighting with this a while but I am in the dark.  any ideas?

Comment: Have you try to  `easy_install reportlab` or  `pip install reportlab`? Both work on my lion mountain computer with python 2.7

Comment: easy_install, yes. Tho it doesn't seem to work, I still can't call it in my code. pip no.  I don't know what pip is, I'll look into it.

Comment: to install pip just do easy_install pip